Undefined reference to osgeo::proj::operation::CoordinateTransformer while using PROJ quick start to c++ API
I am trying to use PROJ quick start C++ API and am trying to execute the code example. I have not made any changes so far and yet get this kind of error.
I have PROJ 8.2 installed from the command sudo apt-get install proj-bin
and also installed it from the source build.
I am not sure why this error appears. If anyone has faced something similar and knows what is to be done, please help. I am still learning C++.
$ g++ try_proj.cpp -lproj
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccmz7Q0R.o: in function `main':
try_proj.cpp:(.text+0x2ed): undefined reference to `osgeo::proj::operation::CoordinateOperation::coordinateTransformer(pj_ctx*) const'
/usr/bin/ld: try_proj.cpp:(.text+0x37c): undefined reference to `osgeo::proj::operation::CoordinateTransformer::transform(PJ_COORD)'
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccmz7Q0R.o: in function `std::default_delete<osgeo::proj::operation::CoordinateTransformer>::operator()(osgeo::proj::operation::CoordinateTransformer*) const':
try_proj.cpp:(.text._ZNKSt14default_deleteIN5osgeo4proj9operation21CoordinateTransformerEEclEPS3_[_ZNKSt14default_deleteIN5osgeo4proj9operation21CoordinateTransformerEEclEPS3_]+0x22): undefined reference to `osgeo::proj::operation::CoordinateTransformer::~CoordinateTransformer()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

The code example is from https://proj.org/en/9.4/development/quickstart_cpp.html .
My code:
'''
#include <cassert>
#include <cmath>  
#include <iomanip> 
#include <iostream>
#include <proj.h>
#include "proj/coordinateoperation.hpp"
#include "proj/crs.hpp"
#include "proj/io.hpp"
#include "proj/util.hpp" 

using namespace NS_PROJ::crs;
using namespace NS_PROJ::io;
using namespace NS_PROJ::operation;
using namespace NS_PROJ::util;


int main(void) {

    auto dbContext = DatabaseContext::create();


    // Instantiate a generic authority factory, that is not tied to a particular

    // authority, to be able to get transformations registered by different

    // authorities. This can only be used for CoordinateOperationContext.

    auto authFactory = AuthorityFactory::create(dbContext, std::string());


    // Create a coordinate operation context, that can be customized to ammend

    // the way coordinate operations are computed. Here we ask for default

    // settings.

    auto coord_op_ctxt =

        CoordinateOperationContext::create(authFactory, nullptr, 0.0);


    // Instantiate a authority factory for EPSG related objects.

    auto authFactoryEPSG = AuthorityFactory::create(dbContext, "EPSG");


    // Instantiate source CRS from EPSG code

    auto sourceCRS = authFactoryEPSG->createCoordinateReferenceSystem("4326");


    // Instantiate target CRS from PROJ.4 string (commented out, the equivalent

    // from the EPSG code)

    // auto targetCRS =

    // authFactoryEPSG->createCoordinateReferenceSystem("32631");

    auto targetCRS =

        NN_CHECK_THROW(nn_dynamic_pointer_cast<CRS>(createFromUserInput(

            "+proj=utm +zone=31 +datum=WGS84 +type=crs", dbContext)));


    // List operations available to transform from EPSG:4326

    // (WGS 84 latitude/longitude) to EPSG:32631 (WGS 84 / UTM zone 31N).

    auto list = CoordinateOperationFactory::create()->createOperations(

        sourceCRS, targetCRS, coord_op_ctxt);


    // Check that we got a non-empty list of operations

    // The list is sorted from the most relevant to the less relevant one.

    // Cf

    // https://proj.org/operations/operations_computation.html#filtering-and-sorting-of-coordinate-operations

    // for more details on the sorting of those operations.

    // For a transformation between a projected CRS and its base CRS, like

    // we do here, there will be only one operation.

    assert(!list.empty());


    // Create an execution context (must only be used by one thread at a time)

    PJ_CONTEXT *ctx = proj_context_create();


    // Create a coordinate transformer from the first operation of the list

    auto transformer = list[0]->coordinateTransformer(ctx);


    // Perform the coordinate transformation.

    PJ_COORD c = {{

        49.0,    // latitude in degree

        2.0,     // longitude in degree

        0.0,     // z ordinate. unused

        HUGE_VAL // time ordinate. unused

    }};

    c = transformer->transform(c);


    // Display result

    std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(3);

    std::cout << "Easting: " << c.v[0] << std::endl;  // should be 426857.988

    std::cout << "Northing: " << c.v[1] << std::endl; // should be 5427937.523


    // Destroy execution context

    proj_context_destroy(ctx);


    return 0;

}


'''
